# The minimum number of bits required for an instruction

Tags: computer-architecture

For a computer architecture, called ComputerA, a MIPS-like instruction set will be used. 64 instructions are reserved for R-type instructions and 64 more instructions are reserved for I-type and J-type instructions in total. Also, there are 128 registers in the system and the size of one register is 64 bits. 
According to the given configurations, what would be the minimum number of bits required for an instruction in ComputerA?
Note that, 
In MIPS, opcode of the all R-type instructions will be 0 (zero). The arithmetic operation is selected according to the function code (funct).
MIPS is a RISC instruction set, therefore its instruction length is fixed.

Comment: What do you think? How many possible instructions are there? How would you encode them?

Comment: Another more complete version of this homework / sample-problem: [minimum number of bits required for R-type, I Type and J type instructions](//stackoverflow.com/q/58635323)

Answer (score 1):

Naively, as you have 128 registers, that means 7-bit register fields.

We would expect that a processor described as MIPS-style RISC, would have R type instructions with 3 register operands.  Thus, an R type instruction would use 3 (register operands) x 7 (bits per register operand) or 21 bits total for the 3 operands.  That leaves 11 bits for opcode (2048 values) — assuming 32-bit fixed sized instructions.

2048 is not a lot of opcode space, if you realize that the opcode field must also be shared by I type and J type instructions as well, plus coprocessor instructions that work on floating point, plus other instruction set extensions like vector operations.

One advantage that the x86/x64 instruction set have with their variable length encodings is a practically infinite ability to extend the instruction set with more opcodes.  This has been used to great advantage over the long history of the ISA, for example, with SIMD instruction extensions, such as with SSE & AVX.

Thought the x86 went through a number of major architectural changes (808x, 386, x64), I think it would have been interesting and somewhat more challenging for a RISC architecture to be similarly extended and re-extended over 40+ years.

Using a MIPS fixed instruction size, you will probably want to relax that a bit to allow for 32-bit and 64-bit instructions, for long term extensibility.

Also, there is often a need for 4 operand instructions (e.g. fused multiply add, 
 and also some vector instructions).  4 x 7 = 28, meaning you need 28 bits to describe 4 register operands, and that means there is no room left for a realistic opcode. 4 operands of 7 bits wide is only be practical in a larger (e.g. 64-bit) instruction.

So, in summary, given 128 registers, I'd support both 32-bit and 64-bit instructions from the start.  Then encode the most common instructions in 32-bits using 11 bit opcode field and 3x7-bit register fields, while allowing some of the 11-bit opcode space to describe 64-bit instructions.

---

What you're doing with 128 registers is a trade off that makes certain complex algorithms work well at the cost of extra space required to encode simpler algorithms.  A smaller number of registers (e.g. 32 as in MIPS) means less registers for complex algorithms, but less bits (3x5=15 vs 3x7=21) required for encoding simpler algorithms into instructions.

All instruction sets have this trade off.  Stack-oriented instruction sets generally are the most compact, and compactness translates into better instruction cache utilization.  However, they require more effort in execution since the same software algorithm encodes into more instructions (not to mention the variable length nature of the instructions).

See also this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/87729/4664) for a discussion comparing various kinds of instruction set styles in the context of an add instruction.